# Custom icons for Custom Post Type category lists

Tags: custom-post-types

I need a simple way of assigning a custom icon whenever a category gets listed.

I am using Custom Post Types and Taxonomies with Views and Types (plugins).

For example, I have a Custom Post Type of Properties > and categories of Commercial/Residential/Hotels (each need an icon).

Maybe assigning a class some how to each would be a good way...

I think this would be a very useful thing for a lot of people so would really appreciate any thoughts/suggestions!

Comment: Where are those lists? Front-end, back-end? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme uses [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) then you should have CSS enough to do this.

Make a `<div>` for your icon.

`<div class="mycategoryicon"></div>`

Add some style.

```
.category-slug .mycategoryicon {
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    background:#ffffff url('slug-icon.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

The "slug" part of the class name should be your actual category slug. Height and width can of course be whatever you need.